# Can't link jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, head, delegation

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RNG</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">

            <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="generateButton">Generate</button>

            <p id="randomNumber"></p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS/jQuery:

```
$("#generateButton").on("click", function() {
    alert("Hello");
})
```

If you are wondering why the only thing my Random Number Generator is supposed to do is saying "Hello", that's because I was trying to figure out why my code wasn't working properly, and then I found out it was jQuery not working.

The file 'script.js' is linked properly though, because when I tried the normal JS alert with no jQuery code, it worked fine.

This is the part of the code where I am linking to jQuery:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Yes, I am linking jQuery from 3 different sources, just in case. That is because the first one didn't work, the second one didn't either, so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: You script goes an the end of the `<body>`

Comment: It isnt jquery not working. The problem is that you are loading your script before the page loads

Comment: You can put it at the bottom of the page as suggested above, or put it in a document ready.

Comment: You need $(document).ready(); so your function will wait until the page loads.

Comment: Or you add 'defer` to script tags.

Comment: You could possibly load different versions of jQuery based upon availability. There are huge differences between 1.11 and 3.3.1. Fair warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `script.js` is where your code lives, when you do

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

There is no `$("#generateButton")`.  You can either move your script to just before the `</body>`, or wrap you code in

```
$(function() {
    //your code goes here
});
```

which tells it to wait for the document to load before executing.

Comment: or add `defer` attribute to script tags.

Answer (score 0):

You just put your code before loading `jquery`, you should put your script after not before.

It make sense in programming to import or load the `lib` before using something from it

```js
$(function(){
  $('#generateButton').click(function(){
     alert("functional");
   })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RNG</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">

            <h1>Random Number Generator</h1>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="generateButton">Generate</button>

            <p id="randomNumber"></p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```